# Large Deviations result for asymptotically independent variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers, large-deviation-theory

I'm wondering if there is a large deviations result for asymptotically independent and identical distributed (a.i.i.d.) variables.

If $\{(X^i_n)_{i=1,\dots,n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  is a sequence of a.i.i.d. variables, does a CLT/large deviation principle exist for the sum of $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X^i_n$?

For a.i.i.d. let's put it in this way (taken more or less from here [[1, chapter 6.3]](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/NotesRGCN.html)):
Fix $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and suppose that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, you have a random vector $(D^{(n)}_i)_{i\in[m]}$, where $[m]=\{1,\dots ,m \}$. We say that $D^{(n)}_i$ are asymptotically independent if we can [couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)) the vector $(D^{(n)}_i)_{i\in[m]}$ to an independent vector $(\hat{D}^{(n)}_i)_{i\in[m]}$ such that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left((D^{(n)}_i)_{i\in[m]} \neq (\hat{D}^{(n)}_i)_{i\in[m]} \right)=0$.

Do you think I can extended this definition to $m=n$ and get a definition of a.i.i.d. if the $\hat{D}^{(n)}_i$ are i.i.d. for all $n$?

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to be _defining_ "asymptotically independent" but it is not a correct definition. I think you mean that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in (joint) distribution to a vector $(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  In general, note that if we converge to a random variable $Z$ in distribution, we also converge to $W$ in distribution, where $W$ is an independent copy of $Z$.  Your second question woudl require a definition of "a.i.i.d." for a doubly indexed sequence (and the definition of a.i.i.d. even for a singly-indexed sequence is not clear).

Comment: @Michael I don't understand why the first definition is not correct. Could you explain me why? I added a different definition, do you think is going to work? thanks

Comment: Because for your first definition it would mean that any time $X_n$ converges in distibution to something (say, $X$), and another random sequence $Y_n$ converges in distribution to something (say, $Y$), you could say they were "asymptotically independent" (according to your incorrect first definition) since we can always assume $X$ and $Y$ are themselves independent (if not, just make $W$ an independent copy of $Y$).  For your second thing I do not know why there are two indices $n$ and $i$ and I do not know which is going to ifninity when you talk about $o(1)$.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned i.i.d should imply a.i.i.d., so I do not see any real problem in the first definition (maybe I'm still wrong?). For the second point, $o(1)$ is referred to $n$, I wrote it in a better way.

Comment: I do not follow your above comment.  In that first definition (and in my previous comment) we can take $X_n=Y_n=X$ for all $n$, no? So they are dependent always, but your definition calls them "asymptotically independent." There is no relevance to "i.i.d." so I do not see why you wrote "As far as I'm concerned i.i.d. should imply a.i.i.d. so I do not see any real problem in teh first definiton."

Comment: Ok I got what you say. I corrected it.